# Semantic Issue (Xcode): Property 'timeSensitiveSetting' not found on object of type 'UNNotificationSettings *'

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement incoming call notification.
I use `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken()` to get APNS token using Firebase but keeps returning a null value.
I've tried to:

- delete the app
- delete podfile.lock
- flutter clean
- flutter run

Reinstalling the app causes a semantic error [image: error]

Please help, can't seem to find the proper solution for this issue.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Just Update to Xcode version to 13+
or you can downgrade the package by running these commands
cd ios

flutter clean

pod deintegrate

rm -fr Pods

rm Podfile

rm -Rf Podfile.lock

rm -Rf .symlinks

rm -Rf Flutter/Flutter.framework

rm -Rf Flutter/Flutter.podspec

pod cache clean --all

same issue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od1or.png

Comment: You should format better the answer

Comment: What version do I downgrade to?

Comment: `v11.2.15` if you follow this change log: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/changelog#1130